# Genetic Algorithm doesn t ever get the optimal solution

Tags: java, algorithm, infinite-loop, genetic-algorithm

I want to solve a sudoku witch is represented in a unidimensional array by a genetic algorithm with the chromosomes and all of that already generated, the genetic algorithm is based on a population (we start with a population of 100 chromosomes) and a fitness function for each one of them, as the algorithm runs the mean of fitness functions of the set of chromosomes gets bigger as the maximun value does too, because off crossovers that we do between the chromosomes and mutations of them too

As the algorithm tries to solve it the maximun value of the fitness reaches 159 but to solve it we need 162, in order to clasify it as a solved sudoku.

I don t know if anyone can tell with this introduction and this code what did we do wrong.

```
        while(!encontrado) {
            encontrado = newPopulation(encontrado,listOfIndividuals,initialSudoku);
        }
```

that function change the populations doing the functions that i told before and it s code is this

```
private static boolean newPopulation (boolean encontrado, List<int[]> listOfIndividuals, int[] initialSudoku) {
        boolean returnBoolean = false;
        List<int[]> aux = new ArrayList<>();
        int añadidos = 0;
        int cnt = 0;
        int max = 0;
        Random alea = new Random();
        while (añadidos != 100 && !returnBoolean) {
            int rnd = alea.nextInt(101);
            int f = fitness(listOfIndividuals.get(cnt),initialSudoku);
            int p = Math.round(((100 * f) - 1800) / 144);
            if (f == 162) {
                System.out.println("HE ENCONTRADO EL FITNESS LIMITE");
                returnBoolean = true;
                aux.add(0,listOfIndividuals.get(cnt));
                continue;
            } else if (p >= rnd) {
                aux.add(listOfIndividuals.get(cnt));
                añadidos++;
                max += f;

                if(añadidos % 2 == 0) {
                    crossover(aux,añadidos-2,añadidos-1);

                }
            }

            if (cnt + 1 == 100) {
                cnt = 0;
            } else {
                cnt++;
            }
        }

        if (!returnBoolean) {
            mutationGroup(aux,initialSudoku);
        }
        System.out.println("The mean is  " + max/aux.size());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        listOfIndividuals.clear();

        for (int j = 0; j < aux.size(); j++) {
            listOfIndividuals.add(aux.get(j));
        }
        return returnBoolean;
    }
```

.............................

Comment: I don't think you have provided enough/the right code to make this answerable (see also: [mre]). We have to trust that your magic numbers are right, which they might not be. One suggestion could be to take a closer look at the solution where it stopped. Is it solved? (yes -> fix your fitness function; no -> ???).

Comment: Assuming your fitness function is ok, this sounds like a classic [stuck in a local minimum](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/54828/how-to-avoid-getting-stuck-on-local-optimum-for-genetic-algorithms) problem. Which does not have an easy solution but there are various methods to avoid it/work around it.

Comment: Genetic algorithms don't necessarily provide optimal solutions. They are intended to provide "good enough" solutions.

Comment: How do you define "optimal solution" for Soduku?  Perhaps `numberOfErrors == 0`, where `numberOfErrors` is a count of "duplicates" in a row, column, or 3 x 3 (for normal size)?

Comment: Off-topic: I wouldn't have `new Random ()` in a loop like that. I would have one `Random` Object, instantiated early.

Comment: AFAIK genetic algorithm is one of a myriad of possible heuristics to solve hard optimization problems. These heuristics generally come with no guarantees. Why do you expect the algorithm to work in this case? To confirm whether this is an implementation issue or short coming of the chosen approach, can you try smaller instances of sudoku (6x6 grid?) Or somehow simplify the problem and see if the generic algorithm works then?